# Unificar dois resultados relacionados em um único SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, join, table

Gostaria de efetuar uma única query no banco que buscaria os ativos que eu quero e no mesmo resultado buscasse as informações dos ativos relacionados.

As tabelas estão estruturadas nessa maneira:

Tabela de ativos

| Id | Symbol | CompanyName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PETR4 | Petrobras |
| 2 | MGLU3 | Magazine Luiza |
| 3 | VALE3 | Vale |

Tabela que relaciona ativos X com ativos Y através dos Ids da tabela acima

| Id | RelatedAssetId | AssetId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |

No momento a minha consulta está assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Assets a
JOIN RelatedAssets ra ON ra.AssetId = a.Id
WHERE a.Symbol LIKE '%PETR4%'
```

E isso me retorna os ativos que batem com "PETR4" e me retorna a tabela de ativos relacionados (que no momento é só o Id) juntamente ao resultado principal.

| Id | Symbol | CompanyName | RelatedAssetId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PETR4 | Petrobras | 2 |
| 1 | PETR4 | Petrobras | 3 |

Problema: Quero que nesse resultado, em vez de vir os Ids dos ativos relacionados, ele efetuasse outro SELECT para buscar Symbol e CompanyName dos ativos relacionados, executando somente uma query, ai o resultado ia ficar algo em torno disso:

| Id | Symbol | CompanyName | RelatedAssetSymbol | RelatedAssetCompanyName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PETR4 | Petrobras | MGLU3 | Magazine Luiza |
| 1 | PETR4 | Petrobras | VALE3 | Vale |

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: As queries parecem não batrr com o resultado , PETR4 não tem Assetid (1) , o * da 1@ query não bate com os campos das duas tabelas. Não entendi o problema.

Answer (score -2):

Você poderia tentar fazer dessa maneira:

```
SELECT a.*,ra.Symbol, ra.CompanyName FROM Assets a
INNER JOIN RelatedAssets ra ON ra.AssetId = a.Id
WHERE a.Symbol LIKE '%PETR4%';
```